# WPF DataGrid Trigger on cell content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers

I have a `datagrid` than contains value comes from a `stored procedure`. All values are set `Bold` as `FontWeight`.

**I'd like to make the text normal when the cell content is equal to 0.**

How can I do that with a trigger?

I've done it like below but it's not working:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Content" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't access `DataGridCell.Content` that way, use a `DataTrigger` instead based on your `DataGrid.SelectedItem.YourProperty` like this:

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

**EDIT:**

Assuming your `DataGridColumns` are text-based then you can use an `IValueConverter` as below:

*Note that if some of data-grid columns are not text-based, this solution still works for those columns which are.*

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FontWeightConverter x:Key="fontWeightConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" 
                       Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                       Path=Content.Text, 
                       Converter={StaticResource fontWeightConverter}}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Converter:

```
public class FontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == "0")
            return FontWeights.Normal;
        return FontWeights.Bold;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good but I need it for all Properties of my Object. I don't want to replicate 12 times this code that I'm sure work

Comment: Perfect. Your edit works. So I assume that There's no way doing it only in XAML. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm 99% sure there is not ; )

Comment: Very good solution. I modified it to work with the whole row. I my case, XAML looked like `<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item, Converter={StaticResource tableStyleConverter}}"` and Convert method had such condition: `(value != null && value is DataRowView && (value as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString()=="Special Value")`

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to define that column:

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataBaseValue}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You can add a binding on the FontWeightof the TextBox with a converter associated to the Text if itself.

Comment: I have 12 columns. I don't want to replicate this code for all colums.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this -

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```